# Calling psexec from a python script doesn't show the whole output

Tags: python, output, psexec

I want to use a python script to show up all local administrators in our domain.

My Code :

```
for line in open(anfangsrechner,"r"):

    zeile = line.strip()

    command ='\\\\' +zeile+ ' -i' ' net' ' localgroup' ' Administratoren'

    abfrage = subprocess.Popen(['PsExec.exe ',command,],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
    # print (abfrage)

    while True:
        line = abfrage.communicate()
        if not line:
            break
        print (line)
```

But I only get this from the `psexec` command:

```
PsExec v2.1 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark
Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't get the whole output. Does someone know how I can fix it?

Comment: What do you get if you run PsExec in a command prompt (not from your Python script?)

Comment: when i use the hole psexec in an cmd i get this

`PsExec v2.1 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Aliasname        Administratoren
Beschreibung     Administratoren haben uneingeschränkten Vollzugriff auf den Com
puter bzw. die Domäne.

Mitglieder

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
ISEW2K\Domain Admins`

so it works in cmd but not in the script :-/ i need to check more then 1000 Maschines - so an script would be nice

Comment: modify your script to print the command it builds up to the console; copy the printed command and see if it executes.

Comment: This is the command the script builds 

`Psexec.exe \\w1378.ise.fhg.de -i net localgroup Administratoren`

When i use this in command line it executes correctly. Executes in the script -> no output shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the arguments as a long string, rather than a list.

The quick fix would be using `shell=True`:

```
abfrage = subprocess.Popen('PsExec.exe '+command, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           shell=True)
```

The right way to do this would be creating a list of arguments and passing it.

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

Comment: Build a list like this

[code]`l = ['\\\\<computer>', '-i', 'net', 'localgroup', 'Administratoren', '>>', '\\\\<domain>\\software\\it\\Admintest\\<computer>.txt']`[/code]

`abfrage = subprocess.Popen(['PsExec.exe ',l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6],],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        print (abfrage)
        abfrage.communicate()`

my output is writen in an external file. The Output is empty ....

Comment: 1. Try removing `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, since you're not piping any input to the command. 2. You can build the list using `['PsExec.exe']+l` instead of adding items one by one.

Comment: My new code line :
`abfrage = subprocess.Popen(['PsExec.exe ']+l,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

But my ouput .txt is empty again ....

Comment: delet -i in the command list get a output but not the whole 

i got this : 
`Aliasname        Administratoren`
Thats first of all okay, but it is useless beacuse their are no Account shown :-/ it looks like that python dont get the output from the subprocess thats executes in the remote workstation

Comment: Try wrapping your program in a shell script and run that script from Python. Make sure the shebang `#!` at the top is correct.

Comment: Can you get me any faq or how to's for wrapping this?

Comment: Just wrap the shell command into a shell script. Search for "Bash script howto", and put your command instead of the one in the example

Comment: start py script in powershell -> Works perfectly! Thank you Adam! you gave me the right tipp :) realy thanks!

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Apologies for having `bash` in mind - in Windows, it's obviously powershell.